# Выборка данных, содержащих русские символы завершается неудачей

Tags: c#, firebird

Использую базу **Firebird** (локальную версию), при выборке не возвращает данные если в ней (выборке) присутствуют русские символы. Хотя выводит данные при обычном *SELECT * FROM TABLE1* нормально и всё отображает. Значит нужно при передачи запроса перекодировать строку запроса в *UTF8*, я так думаю.
Как это сделать?

P.S. Насчет выбора кодировок - пролистал все кодировки выбираются только - UTF-8, NONE, ASCII

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего у Вас в параметрах запроса не та кодировка, то есть база в UTF-8 а параметры передаете в Win1251